# admin and user login form

Tags: php, html

Hi can anyone see what im doing wrong.  Im using the one login for both user and admin and it is directing me to the admin page but when i enter a users name and password its saying username and password incorrect.  Have messed with this for hours.

PHP FILE:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['Submit']))   //Check if the login form has been submitted
{   
    include ('dbconnection.php');

    //Get the values from the new user form
    $pw = md5($_POST['Password']); //Note use of MD5 hash function
    $username = $_POST['UserName'];

    //Set up and execute the INSERT query
    $query = "SELECT * FROM users Where UserName = '$username' AND Password ='$pw' AND Role = 'User' ";
    $result=mysql_query($query);  //Get the query result
    $num=mysql_numrows($result);  //Get number of records returned 


    if ($num)  //Logon is successful - redirect to restricted home page
    {
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['UserId']=$username; //Save the username in a session variable
        mysql_close($connection); //close database connection
            header("Location: Index.php?Successful"); //display the restricted page

    }
    else    //Logon has failed - reload the logon page
    {
    mysql_close($connection);//close database connection
        header("Location: Emersrecipes.php?err"); //id user does not exist in db directs back to login page with an error   

    }
}
?>

<?php

if(isset($_POST['Submit']))   //Check if the login form has been submitted
{   
    include ('dbconnection.php');

    //Get the values from the new user form
    $pw = md5($_POST['Password']); //Note use of MD5 hash function
    $username = $_POST['UserName'];

    //Set up and execute the INSERT query
    $query = "SELECT * FROM users Where UserName = '$username' AND Password ='$pw' AND Role = 'Administrator' ";
    $result=mysql_query($query);  //Get the query result
    $num=mysql_numrows($result);  //Get number of records returned 


    if ($num)  //Logon is successful - redirect to restricted home page
    {
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['UserId']=$username; //Save the username in a session variable
        mysql_close($connection); //close database connection
            header("Location: Admin\admin.php?Successful"); //display the restricted page

    }
    else    //Logon has failed - reload the logon page
    {
    mysql_close($connection);//close database connection
        header("Location: Emersrecipes.php?err"); //id user does not exist in db directs back to login page with an error   

    }
}
?>
```

HTML FORM

```
<div class = 'grd6'>

            <article>
            <p>Welcome today is <?php echo date ('M j, Y');?></P>
            </article>
            <form class = 'loginform' method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" name="loginform">
            <h2>User Login Form</h2>
            Username:<input name="UserName" type="text"   size="30" maxlength="30" placeholder='Enter Your Name' required/><br />
            Password:<input name="Password" type="Password" placeholder= 'Enter your password' required  size="30" maxlength="30" /><br /><p>
            <input name="Submit" type="Submit" value="Login" />
            <?php include ('php\Login.php')?>
            </form>     
            </div>
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injections. You should read on [how to prevent them in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/53114).

Comment: mysql_num_rows.  Turn on error reporting

Comment: 1. SQL injection 2. no escaping of strings from user input 3. no `exit;` after `header()` 4. use of `md5` 5. code style.. Many things to improve young padawan!

Comment: i know I'm open to sql injection was going to put in the stored procedure later.  Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can minify your code like this

```
if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
{   
include ('dbconnection.php');
$pw = md5($_POST['Password']); 
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['UserName']);
//mysql_real_escape_string wont save you from sql injection so user PDO/mysqli

$query = "SELECT * FROM users Where UserName = '$username' AND Password ='$pw'";
$result=mysql_query($query);  
$num=mysql_numrows($result);  

if ($num>0) 
{
  $row= mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
  if($row['role']=='Administrator')
  {
   //Admin login
  }   
  if($row['role']=='User')
  {
   //user login
  }
}
```

Comment: Great that works thanks, where would i place my error and redirect back to homepage then                                            else    //Logon has failed - reload the logon page
    {
    mysql_close($connection);//close database connection
        header("Location: Emersrecipes.php?err"); //id user does not exist in db directs back to login page with an error   

    }

Comment: write these in else part,i forgot to write it :D

Comment: i put them in the else part and it makes it not work again, goes back to how it was before, sorry im really new to php.  any help really appreciated